# Test ReactJS custom hook to load images with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test the onload function of a custom hook to load image, but when i run the test, it skips the onload.

Hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useImage = (src: string) => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = src;
        image.onload = () => {
            return setLoaded(true); //can't test it
        };
    }, [src]);

    return { loaded };
};

export default useImage;
```

Test:

```
import {
    renderHook,
    waitFor,
} from "@testing-library/react";
import useImage from "./useImage";

describe("useImage", () => {

    it("Loads a data url into an image element", async () => {

        const img = new Image();
        img.src = "foo";

        const { result } = renderHook(() => useImage("foo"));

        await waitFor(() =>
            expect(result.current).toStrictEqual({ loaded: true }) // loaded is always false
        );

    });
});
```

How can i make the test run the onload inside the useEffect? I'm using Jest and Typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `useImage` hook is not doing anything except loading the image, then set a state. If this is only for demonstration purposes, that's fine, otherwise, you should look into what you are trying to achieve with that hook.

Regarding the test, if you are using `jest` and `jsdom` to test. Then `jsdom` [only fire load events when they actually load something](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816#issuecomment-310106280). Meaning you must use a real image in the `src` AND change some jest configuration like this:

In `package.json`, if you use jest.config.js, then please refer to the official doc for the equivalent.

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom", // we need this line
    "transform": {
      "node_modules/variables/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
      "resources": "usable" // we need this line
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!variables/.*)"
    ]
  },
```

You'll also need to install [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)

```
 npm i canvas
```

Then your test is going to pass now. But, if you find this is a bit problematic to install a new dependency and change how the default test framework works, then you can [mock the Image object implementation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816#issuecomment-432496573) instead, personally, I would prefer this way:

```
const LOAD_FAILURE_SRC = 'LOAD_FAILURE_SRC';
const LOAD_SUCCESS_SRC = 'LOAD_SUCCESS_SRC';
beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(global.Image.prototype, 'src', {
        set(src) {
            if (src === LOAD_FAILURE_SRC) {
                setTimeout(() => this.onerror(new Error('mocked error')));
            } else if (src === LOAD_SUCCESS_SRC) {
                setTimeout(() => this.onload());
            }
        },
    });
});
```